# Java Scripting Engine class instantiation

Tags: java, javascript, scripting

I'm trying to implement scripting endpoint in our application, but I have a problem:
Is it possible to instantiate an object that is instance of abstract class with implemented methods? In Java it will look like:

```
SimpleObject obj = new SimpleObject("contructor arg0") {    
   public void doCustomAction() {
     System.out.println("Action");
   }
}
```

`SimpleObject` is an abstract class with abstract method `doCustomAction`
How to do such thing via Java Scripting Engine? I'm trying to do in the following way:

```
obj1 = new SimpleObject("value1") {
    doCustomAction : function() {
       //Do smth.
    }
}
```

But engine throws such exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException:
   error instantiating (JavaAdapter: first arg should be interface Class (<Unknown source>#1)): 
  class SimpleObject is interface or abstract (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extend your abstract class in Java, something like [MouseAdapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html) does with its interfaces, then in javascript you use this "adapter", like:

In Java:

```
public abstract class SimpleObject {
   abstract void doCustomAction();
}
public class SimpleObjectAdapter extends SimpleObject {
   void doCustomAction(){}
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
obj1 = new JavaAdapter(SimpleObjectAdapter,{
    doCustomAction : function() {
       //Do smth.
    }
});
```

Edit:
You could do it without the "adapter", just do:

```
obj1 = new JavaAdapter(Packages.SimpleObject, {
   doCustomAction: function(){
      //Do smth.
   }
});
```